# What is the limiting distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Z_{i}+1/n)/\sqrt{n}$?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $Z_{i} \sim N(0,1)$ (where $N(0,1)$ is a normal distribution) and $Z_1,Z_2,...$ are idependent. Find the limiting distribution of
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{Z_{i}+1/n}{\sqrt{n}}$$
I want use the moment generating functions to find the limiting distribution, but couldn't find it.
Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Start from
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{Z_{i}+1/n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{Z_{i}}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}.
$$
Then using the assumption on the random $Z_i$, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{Z_{i}}{\sqrt{n}}$ has a standard normal distribution so basically, you are asked to find the limiting distribution of $Z+n^{-1/2}$ where $Z$ has a standard normal distribution.

Comment: I dont understand can you be more detailed?

Comment: What don't you understand exactly? The fact that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{Z_{i}}{\sqrt{n}}$ has a standard normal distribution?